# Openshift disable build quota

Tags: linux, centos7, openshift-origin, cgroups

I'm trying to use buildconfig/builds in OpenShift. The machine is a CentOS 7.3 with kernel 4.5.7-std-3

Unfortunately the kernel I'm using doesn't have `CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH` enabled.

```
gunzip < /proc/config.gz | grep CFS
# CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH is not set
```

Therefore every build I try instantly fails with:

```
error: failed to retrieve cgroup limits: cannot determine cgroup limits: open /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_quota_us: no such file or directory
```

Is there a way to bypass this?
I already disabled the quotas inside the kubelet section on the node config file without success.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's currently necessary to enable cgroups for builds to work properly, you can see additional discussion of this issue here:
https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/8074